# Why I am getting a segmentation fault opening Guitar Pro?

Tags: 11.04, 64-bit, segmentation-fault

I am having this hard time with Guitar Pro on Ubuntu 11.04.

I am getting a segmentation fault error from the application, but it used to work before on Ubuntu 10.10, suddenly it stopped working.

This is the code from terminal:

```
usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 

(:3559): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so 

/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 

(:3559): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so 

(:3559): Gtk-WARNING **: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 

(:3559): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed 

(:3559): Gtk-WARNING **: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 

(:3559): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed
```

/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

```
(:3559): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so 

/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 

(:3559): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so 

(:3559): Gtk-WARNING **: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 

(:3559): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed
```

/usr/lib/gio/modules/libgiobamf.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgiobamf.so 
/usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so

```
(:3559): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'dialog-information' for stock: Unable to load image-loading module: /usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so: /usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 

(:3559): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed 

** (:3559): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_render_icon: assertion `base_pixbuf != NULL' failed 

(:3559): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_style_render_icon: assertion `pixbuf != NULL' failed 

(:3559): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed 

(:3559): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed 

(:3559): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed 
Segmentation fault
```

Any ideas? I am not very Ubuntu savvy on this type of things.

I am using Ubuntu 64 bit

Comment: Actually there's a bug on ia32-libs package: http://getsatisfaction.guitar-pro.com/arobas_music/topics/after_ubuntu_11_04_upgrade_i_cant_open_gp6 The workaround is on the website, the Guitar Pro developers are working in order to get this fixed. –

Answer (score 2):

Try running

```
unset UBUNTU_MENUPROXY
unset GTK_IM_MODULE
unset QT_IM_MODULE
```

in the terminal before launching your program, but make sure you run the program in the same terminal session. If you open a new tab, for example, you'll have run those commands again.

Comment: I am going to do that and I'll tell you about it

Comment: Now this is what I got:

Comment: Did that, now I obtain this: http://pastebin.com/7ei7cpfj

The segmentation fault keeps appearing :S

Comment: I had a problem running IntelliJ on 11.10 and this worked for me. The problem manifested as short cut keys not working - fixing the problem with libappmenu.so seems to make everything work much better. Cheers!

Comment: it worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem myself. Running Guitar Pro with root privileges and then updating the software to the latest version with the update manager fixes this. You should be able to run it normally afterwards without issue, as this was a glitch with guitar pro and 11.04.

Use this command to run Guitar Pro with root privileges:

```
gksudo /opt/GuitarPro6/gp-launcher.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I´m running it on 64-bit, too.

You´ll get it by running:

```
mv ~/.ArobasMusic ~/.ArobasMusicbkp
```

in your Terminal!

Comment: Actually there's a bug on ia32-libs package: http://getsatisfaction.guitar-pro.com/arobas_music/topics/after_ubuntu_11_04_upgrade_i_cant_open_gp6

The workaround is on the website, the Guitar Pro developers are working in order to get this fixed.